# How would you extract a part (pattern) of a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a string like this `"Token: 1830-5868-4807-2907-3850, Units : 36.2, Debt Amount : 0.00, Debt Remaining : 0, Recept No: 84657081"`

I want to get just this `1830-5868-4807-2907-3850`

Comment: Use [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Answer (score 0):

Use `slice` method:

```
const str = "Token: 1830-5868-4807-2907-3850, Units : 36.2, Debt Amount : 0.00, Debt Remaining : 0, Recept No: 84657081"

const result = str.slice(6, 31)

console.log(result) // output: '1830-5868-4807-2907-3850'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a (non-greedy) regex to grab the sequence between "Token: " and the first comma:

```js
const str = "Token: 1830-5868-4807-2907-3850, Units : 36.2, Debt Amount : 0.00, Debt Remaining : 0, Recept No: 84657081";
const token = str.match('Token: (.*?), .*')[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you will have only one sub string matching the pattern you can use  [string.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```js
const paragraph = "Token: 1830-5868-4807-2907-3850, Units : 36.2, Debt Amount : 0.00, Debt Remaining : 0, Recept No: 84657081";
const regex = /\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}/g;
const found = paragraph.match(regex);

console.log(found[0]);
```